# TeamCity configuration doesn't persist inside docker

Tags: docker, teamcity

I've setup TeamCity inside a docker image and I can access it via localhost but everytime I restart my docker, TeamCity always ask for configuration again (from the beginning, meaning that I have to reconfigure the whole TeamCity again).

How do I make my configuration persist?

Comment: Did you commit your changes? See `docker commit --help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make my configuration persist?

You can [mount a volume or use a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/), in order to persist that configuration.

If you do not, the copy-on-write mechanism used by docker would remove any modification of [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/rm/) (unless you [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/) right after a [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/stop/))

For example, this [Teamcity docker project](https://github.com/sjoerdmulder/teamcity-docker) runs it with a mounted volume:

```
docker run --link some-postgres:postgres \
  -v <teamcitydir>:/var/lib/teamcity -d \
  sjoerdmulder/teamcity:latest
```